# git diff HEAD^! shows less files than HEAD^..HEAD

Tags: git, version-control, diff

I am trying to infer a list of changed files from merge commits. I was always doing this with a command

```
git diff --name-status HEAD^!
```

recently I found that this command doesn't show me all changed files. How to understand a reason? What exactly notaion `HEAD^!` mean? And how it differs with `HEAD^..HEAD`?

Can this be related to the fact, that merge commit has two parents?

I am assuming commits are squashed before merge. If they were not, can this affect? How to see?

I have

```
(base) dims@<macbook>:~/myproject# git diff --name-status HEAD^!   
MM      schemas/confirmation_served/model.json
MM      schemas/page_loaded/model.json
MM      schemas/review_page_loaded/model.json
(base) dims@<macbook>:~/myproject# git diff --name-status HEAD^..HEAD
A       schemas/confirmation_served/confirmation_served.v2.0.0.json
M       schemas/confirmation_served/model.json
A       schemas/detail.v2.0.0.json
A       schemas/page_loaded/page_loaded.v2.0.0.json
M       schemas/page_loaded/model.json
A       schemas/review_page_loaded/review_page_loaded.v2.0.0.json
M       schemas/review_page_loaded/model.json
A       schemas/transaction_detail.v3.0.0.json
A       schemas/extra_transaction_detail.v3.0.0.json
A       schemas/bill.v2.0.0.json
```

What does double `MM` mean?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions/2.22.0 "Revision range summary" part.

Comment: ... the eyes read but the mind is somewhere else ... sorry, can you expain please exactly for my case?

Comment: Are you standing on a merge-commit right now?

Comment: Yeah, quite cryptic. Try `git log --oneline <range>` with each of these notations to see what commits are included in each.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions/2.22.0#Documentation/revisions.txt-emltrevgtemegemHEADem-1 explains what `<rev>^!`. Then because `^!` excludes all its parents, it should show you only whatever was introduced in the merge commit _itself_ (assuming `HEAD` is a merge commit, which is likely). If you did `HEAD^..HEAD` then that will _include_ all changes that are coming from parents **other than** the first parent.

Comment: @eftshift0 exactly

Comment: @eftshift0 what is "first parent"?

Comment: Commits have at least one _parent_ commit (except for the first commit of a branch, which has _no_ parent). _Normal_ commits have a single parent..... but _merge_ commits have more than one parent. `some-commit^` or `some-commit~` is translated to `some-commits's first parent`.... `some-commit^N` is `some-commit`'s Nth parent (on a merge commit) and `some-commit~N` is the commit resulting from going back N commits always picking the first parent.

Comment: @eftshift0 yes, but which one of two merge commit parents is first and which one is second?